# ReactJS / NodeJS: How to pass variables to backend in api request

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I am working on building a website and wish to expand my API functionality.
I have a frontend react app and a backend express nodejs server.

I have another local webserver that hosts some data about football matches. Data about the round and year is served by calling `/nrl/week={week}&season={year}`.

The react app is currently set up such that axios sends a request to the backend and the backend sends a request to the other webserver.

`const data = await axios.get('/nrl')` frontend code

`request('http://127.0.0.1:5000/nrl/week=20&season=2022',` backend code

I want to be able to make a request from the front end to the backend specifying what week and season, as currently its hardcoded.

Thanks

Comment: `request` is deprecated and has been for some time. I would recommend Axios or [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got)

Comment: Are you sure that URL is correct? Usually URL query parameters start with a `?`

Comment: Axios works in the backend side of this too? I'll change it. 
Ill double check the URL

Comment: Yep, Axios works in browsers and NodeJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your request from the front-end with URL query parameters and forward those through to the other API

**Front-end**

```js
// These will probably come from user selection / input
const week = 20;
const season = 2022;

const { data } = await axios.get("/nrl", {
  params: { week, season }
});
```

**Express**

```js
app.get("/nrl", async (req, res, next) => {
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(req.query);

  // FYI `request` is deprecated. See https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
  request(
    `http://127.0.0.1:5000/nrl/?${queryParams}`,
    (err, response, body) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return next(err);
      }

      res.type(response.headers["content-type"]).send(body);
    }
  );

  // or if you switch to Axios
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/nrl/", {
      params: req.query,
    });
    res.send(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.toJSON());
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: How does my frontend request know to use that particular backend controller? I don't understand how its called.

Comment: @Bigred I assumed you already had an app route handling `/nrl`. I've updated my answer to be a bit more specific